# How To Find Datatypes information in oracle schema?

Tags: oracle, types

How to get all the datatypes information in oracle schema.

Whole datatypes with all details like name type pression etc.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have the correct access, this should do it..

```
select distinct data_type,data_length,data_precision,data_scale 
from all_tab_columns
```

Comment: thanks Stevie but I need to find all the distinct datatypes which are currently in use.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has an internal [Data Dictionary](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96524/c05dicti.htm) with meta data about the database:

> One of the most important parts of an
>   Oracle database is its data
>   dictionary, which is a read-only set
>   of tables that provides information
>   about the database. A data dictionary
>   contains:
>
> - The definitions of all schema objects
>     in the database (tables, views,
>     indexes, clusters, synonyms,
>     sequences, procedures, functions,
>     packages, triggers, and so on)
> - How
>     much space has been allocated for, and
>     is currently used by, the schema
>     objects
> - Default values for columns
> - Integrity constraint information
> - The
>     names of Oracle users
> - Privileges and
>     roles each user has been granted
> - Auditing information, such as who has
>     accessed or updated various schema
>     objects
> - Other general database
>     information  The data dictionary is
>     structured in tables and views, just
>     like other database data

One of the tables is [`ALL_TAB_COLS`](http://ss64.com/orad/ALL_TAB_COLS.html), which has data about the columns of the tables, their data type prevision etc.

You can do a distinct select on the `DATA_TYPE` column of the table to find the data types currently in use.

List of all data dictionary views [here](http://ss64.com/orad/).

PS: The fact that some data type is not used today does not mean that it will not be used in the future. You may want to either use all the [data types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm), or query `ALL_TAB_COLS` frequently, depending on your requirement.