# count of fields with particular data type in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have used the following query to get count of columns with a particular datatype from a table. But I am not getting correct count, Its lot more than what I expect. What could be wrong with this query?

```
 select count(t.data_type)
 from all_tab_columns t
 where t.TABLE_NAME='REG_ENG_FILES' and t.DATA_TYPE='VARCHAR2'
```

Is it possible to get count from metadata?

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569820/how-to-find-datatypes-information-in-oracle-schema)

Comment: The query seems to be working correctly. Could you provide the DESC of your REG_ENG_FILES?

Comment: Could there be different schemas in your database with the same table name?

Comment: @Turophile, no there is no different schema with same name, Is it possible?

Comment: @Turophile, I rechecked it, there are more than one schema. thanks it was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Turophile says is that you can have schema1, schema2 having both a table `REG_ENG_FILES`. To be more specific, you can use:

```
select count(t.data_type)
from all_tab_columns t
where t.TABLE_NAME='REG_ENG_FILES'
  and t.OWNER='MYSCHEMA'
  and t.DATA_TYPE='VARCHAR2'
;
```